# How to send result of Jquery to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

**View:**

```
<div class="item">
<!-- Item's image -->
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/1/" alt="">
<!-- Item details -->
<div class="item-dtls">
<!-- product title -->
<h4><a href="#" >Lorem product</a></h4>
<!-- price -->
<span class="price lblue"  >$23.00</span>
</div>
<!-- add to cart btn -->
<div class="ecom bg-lblue">
<a class="btn" href="#" ">Add to cart</a>
</div>
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('a.btn').click(function () {
var container = $(this).closest('.item');
var title = container.find('.item-dtls > h4 > a').html();
var price = container.find('.price').html();
alert('Title: ' + title + ', Price: ' + price);
});
```

How to send title and price to action result ?

Comment: update your complete code of the view

Comment: You can use AJAX to communicate to server side: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Use `ajax` to do that. You should update your previous question where I answered.

Answer (score 2):

ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'@(Url.Action("SomeAction", "Some"))',
    data: {title:title, price:price},
    success:function(data){
        //data is response from action
        ....
    }
});
```

Action itself:

```
public class SomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult SomeAction(string title, string price)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And use text() insteadof html(), or you get exception of dangerous request if u send html code to action:

```
var title = container.find('.item-dtls > h4 > a').text();
var price = container.find('.price').text();
```